# weblogic.xml file is missing in WAR file ...Not able to generate WAR file (***with weblogic.xml file) for WebLogic server using Maven in Eclipse.

Tags: xml, maven

I tried to search for a solution but no answers so far... I have a Java Dynamic Web Project and trying to build a WAR file and deploy it in WebLogic application server using Maven in Eclipse Luna. I am not able to generate a **WAR file with weblogic.xml file** using Maven tool in Eclipse.

Here are the steps...

**Project --> Right click --> Run as Maven build --> clean install --> WAR file is generated with web.xml file but weblogic.xml is missing.** Do i need to provide any configuration in pom.xml file project specific to generate the weblogic.xml file for WebLogic 11 application server? Just need to generate the WAR file with web.xml file and Weblogic.xml file and i need to manually deploy it in WebLogic application server through console.

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>APL_LGS_DownoadService</groupId>
    <artifactId>APL_LGS_DownloadService</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>WEB-INF/weblogic.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Maven uses convention over configuration. What happens when you remove the <configuration> tag? It may just bundle it for you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. Without <configuration> tag in pom.xml file, build was failed with the error....  Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1So, i added only <configuration>
  <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml></configuration>         and build is success now, but still the weblogic.xml is missing... Not sure what am i missing in the pom.xml file! Its taking my 3 days of time still not able to figure it out.

Comment: I would think you'd be able to remove the <webResources> tag. Confirm that weblogic.xml is indeed under the WEB-INF folder. Then try 1. right click on project -> Maven -> update project -> OK  2. Run as -> Maven clean  3. Run as -> Maven install.

Comment: <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>APL_LGS_DownoadService</groupId>
 <artifactId>APL_LGS_DownloadService</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 
 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

Comment: <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>JBoss repository</id>
   <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
   <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
  </dependency>

 </dependencies>

Comment: <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>

Comment: Still the WAR file is generated with the above pom.xml file without Weblogic.xml file even after right click on project -> Maven -> update project -> OK 2. Run as -> Maven clean 3. Run as -> Maven install.

Comment: I am not concerned about the weblogic.xml file location/structure. This WAR  file should be deployed in WebLogic application server. Not sure why the same WAR file is working in Tomcat but not in WebLogic application server? Is it mandatory to have weblogic.xml file within WAR file to be deployed in WebLogic application server?

Comment: We deploy our application to Weblogic as EARs. In that case, weblogic.xml is not required under the War module. If you deploy a standalone war, then weblogic.xml may be required. Try to place the weblogic.xml file where it should be after the project builds. It should deploy like that.

Comment: What's the deployment error?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you'd be able to remove the  tag. 
ALso confirm that weblogic.xml is indeed under the WEB-INF folder. 
Then try 
 1. right click on project -> Maven -> update project -> OK
 2. right click on project -> Run as -> Maven clean
 3. right click on project -> Run as -> Maven install

If that fails I'd try to create a new Maven project to build/test with.
File -> New -> Other -> Maven Project
Use org.apache.maven.archetypes : maven-archetype-webapp : 1.0

Drop weblogic.xml under the WEB-INF folder and do maven clean install.

If it works you can compare the 'Effective POM' tabs to see what's different between the new project and the one that's broken.

Comment: Hi, i tried creating a new Maven project in Eclipse --> File --> New --> Maven Project --> Next --> maven-archetype-webapp : 1.0 --> Group ID (com.sample2) --> Artifact ID (sample2) --> Finish. Maven project created with the below structure. 1. src --> main --> resources
2. Java Resources --> src/main/resources
May i know where to create my java class? It's confusing now with this structure. Maven --> clean--> install created WAR file with no class file. Please help me with the steps to create a Java class file, pom.xml and web.xml structure wise. I am stuck with this for a week.

Comment: Java classes go in src/main/java. Refer to this https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html   and this http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/

Comment: Thanks, i found the solution and it might be helpful to others. The issue is with the web.xml file. i changed it as, <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
 version="2.5">                                                                                                                  instead of 3.0. it worked fine and the deployment is success.